# Docker: Why Executing AWS Lambda is extremely slow?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, docker, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am developing a REST API with AWS Lambda and API Gateway. When invoked locally with docker, I experience extreme slowness. I am using Postman tool to execute the URLs, each URL will take 5-8 seconds to give back anything.

To demonstrate this I don't need to post any code, because the default `hello-world` Java app that you can get by executing the command `sam init` also having the same issue. So this is not code related but something else. FYI, from `sam init` I am downloading the java 11 based example.

How can I improve the performance when I am running my app from inside the Docker?

Comment: Can you provide any sample code of what your application is doing?